# How do I structure my mongoose schemas if have variations in user roles (seller vs buyer)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, database

My app has multiple user types. Registration for each requires different information (ex: ssn from seller, address from buyer). So it makes sense they would be different schemas. But they do share many fields as well (ex: name, email, password, secruity questions, phone, etc).

What do I do? CopyPaste schema from one to another?

2nd problem is I'm using passportjs, and it asks for user model ...

like this in app.js

```
var User = require('./models/User');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

So if I do use different schemas than how would i handle this?

I have tired inheritance but I dont think there is inheritance in Mongoose. And what about validations I dont want seller validations to run on buyer they will raise error: no ssn was given, vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can handle this.

On the Passport part, I would recommend decoupling your Account model from your User model.  User has the profile stuff, while Account has the login stuff.  A User has an Account as well (by reference probably).

On the roles part, I would likewise recommend that each User has a Role, which is likely an embedded document. Part of that can be common fields.  For unique fields, I would start simply with just a Mixed type object, so you can stuff whatever you want into it.

Comment: if user types have role as embeded document, then to know wether user is seller or buyer, i'd have to do something like this `user.role.type == 1` whereas right now it's `user.seller == true`.  can you show an example schema

Comment: Like I said, there's different ways to handle it depending on what you want to optimize for.